# Does the DXA Mobile Implementation expose the device/browser screen width and or height?

Tags: dxa, ambient-data-framework, context-engine, sdl-tridion, sdl-mobile

I've been following the documentation for the DXA installation and it is a bit confusing what is needed in order to get certain "mobile" device information. For example, I only need the screen width of the device.

1. Is it possible to get such information for "free"?
2. Do I need an SDL Mobile license for that?
3. Do I need the Device Database installed and if so, do I need a license to get the Device Database installed?

I already opened a ticket to whitelist the IP of the server where I'll be running DXA. 
Based on the documentation I won't get "First Request Device Recognition", does it mean I get that information ons subsequent requests?

How is that done? Every time I check the `@WebRequestContext.ScreenWidth` property, I always get "Medium" both from my iPad, my iPhone and my Desktop.

Can you guys help me on which steps do I need to take to get the screen width properly populated?

I also checked the Claims and I always get the same valus for width and height, both in the browser and the device:
[image]
Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ADF is using default values for the displayWidth and displayHeight claims, which means either:

1. Your device database is not up to date (or been created)
2. The Javascript/Cookie that sets these values in the absence of a device database is not functioning

I would check that your browsers are not blocking JS or cookies, and that there are no JS errors in the console. Are you running DXA out of the box? If so it should 'just work' for the 2nd and subsequent requests (1st request is different as there is no cookie, so uses ADF defaults.

Comment: 1. The device database creation gives me an error but I see the data files being created, but I don't have a way to validate it. I checked with support and they sent me a link to some q&a site, which didn't help. What Javascript/Cookie are you talking about? I have DXA running out of the box (with my own models and views) and I even configured the IMediaHelper you use SDL Mobile. However I don't know if my device database is properly created and I don' tknow what javascript/cookie I should be looking at.